# Triple DES in Ruby by using existing Python code

Tags: python, ruby, encryption, cryptography, tripledes

As part of one our conversion from python to ruby, we need to re write the  existing python code to ruby. Encryption code in python is as follows.

```
import md5;
from pyDes import *

PrivateKey = 'secret';
XmlToEncrypt = 'Hello';

#Generate an MD5Hash on the Private key
m = md5.new(PrivateKey);

#create a 16 byte string
key = m.digest();

#setup the Triple DES class from pyDes
payloadEncrypt = triple_des(key, ECB, '\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0', pad=None, padmode=PAD_PKCS5);

#Encrypt the xml Payload 
EncryptedXML = payloadEncrypt.encrypt(XmlToEncrypt).encode('base64');

#Finally convert to base64, this string will be used in creating the HMAC signature
EncryptedXMLString = EncryptedXML.encode('base64');

print "Encrypted: " + EncryptedXML;
```

We tried to implement the same as follows.

```
def triple_des_xml_payload(data)
    # Get xml payload data and apply triple-des algorithm on it and convert it to base64
    md5 = Digest::MD5.hexdigest(@private_key) # Create a md5 Hash
    cipher = OpenSSL::Cipher::Cipher.new('DES-ECB')
    cipher.encrypt
    cipher.pkcs5_keyivgen(md5) 
    output = cipher.update(data)
    output << cipher.final
    encrypted_xml = Base64.encode64(output)
    puts encrypted_xml
    return encrypted_xml
 end
```

But this ruby implementation not giving the same results as python.

Can we get some help to resolve this soon.

Comment: If I am not mistaken, Ruby OpenSSL wrapper uses `3DES` to name triple DES. The mode of operation seems to be the same, but make sure you are also using the same key size. You can specify it in the name of your cipher. Also, it's recommended to use [`OpenSSL::PKCS5`](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0.0/libdoc/openssl/rdoc/OpenSSL/PKCS5.html), instead of [`cipher.pkcs5_keyivgen`](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0.0/libdoc/openssl/rdoc/OpenSSL/Cipher.html#pkcs5_keyivgen-method).

Comment: we have changed PKCS5, but still   
**def get_key(pass)
    salt = OpenSSL::Random.random_bytes(32)
    iter = 20000
    key_len = 32
    key = OpenSSL::PKCS5.pbkdf2_hmac_sha1(pass, salt, iter, key_len)
  end** but still no luck

Answer (score 3):

Your Python code is using 2-key (or “Keying option 2”) triple DES (since you are using the 128 bit result of an MD5 hash as the key). To get the same in Ruby you need to specify the cipher as `des-ede-ecb`.

In the Python code you use the MD5 hash of the secret as the key. So in your Ruby you don’t need `pkcs5_keyivgen`, just use this hash result directly as the key. Also make sure you use the actual hash digest, *not* the hex representation.

Combining these two issues:

```
def triple_des_xml_payload(data)
  # Note: digest not hexdigest
  key = Digest::MD5.digest(@private_key) # Create a md5 Hash
  # Just use OpenSSL::Cipher, not OpenSSL::Cipher::Cipher
  cipher = OpenSSL::Cipher.new('des-ede-ecb')
  cipher.encrypt
  # Specify the key (no need for pkcs5_keyivgen)
  cipher.key = key

  output = cipher.update(data)
  output << cipher.final

  encrypted_xml = Base64.encode64(output)

  return encrypted_xml
 end
```

Note that in reality you probably should use something like PBKDF2, this is just to replicate what you already have in your Python. (You should ideally also move from triple DES to something like AES, and you certainly should use a different mode than ECB).